# Android: Circle counter on top of the image

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know, is there any library on Github for example, or something else for adding a circle counter on top of an image:

[image]

Actually, I can create a new `FrameLayout` and position every element, but I am not sure that this is the right way. I searched for something like that, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: His correct name it's `Badger`,  there are a lot of libraries to do that.

Comment: Oh, come on... it's just a TextView with a circular ShapeDrawable as a background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a drawable file name `badge_background.xml` and paste the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

</shape>
```

Then set this drawable to the background of the textview, like below.

```
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/viewLayout" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="12dp">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/view" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:contentDescription="@string/imageDescription" android:src="@drawable/view" /> 
  <TextView android:id="@+id/viewBad" android:layout_width="20dip" android:layout_height="20dip" android:clickable="false" android:layout_marginStart="5dp" android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/badge_background" android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:text="5" android:textColor="@color/white" android:visibility="gone" /> 
  </FrameLayout>
```